# How to Install Tkinter in Python3.6 Centos7 Offline

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visualization

I'm trying to install Tkinter (since I get no module named '_tkinter' errors) on an offline Centos7 machine.  Thus pip install / apt-get won't work.

I have tkinter for python2.7 and tried copying the folders over but no luck.  It seems there doesn't exist wheel files for 3.6 for tkinter.

Is there a way I can get the version of Python3.6 to look at the Tkinter from Python2.7?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this tkinter folder, like you did the Python 2.7 version [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/**init**.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py)